# how to take screen shot from any screen flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, screenshot

I have a flutter application which have more than 10 screens and I need to take a screenshot of the opened screen when a specific event happened [event not by user so I don't know the opened screen] without .

I want a General solution because I tried [Screen shot package](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot)
But I need to wrap every page with ScreenShot and save its controller but don't work because It's not expandable if I increase the pages and I some cases the event come from a thread and a can't know the opened page now